# как вставить перенос строки в текст если он часть объекта

Tags: javascript

есть вот такой объект

```
var ENParam = {  
    title: 'MAIN TECHNICAL CHARACTERISTICS',  
    importParamText: 'MAIN CHARACTERISTICS:',  
    Capacity: 'Capacity (t/h)',  
    Accuracy: 'Accuracy, (%)',  
    Voltage: 'Voltage / Frequency, (V/Hz)',  
    Power: 'Power, (KW)',  
    Weight:'Weight, (KG)'  
}
```

и мне нужно что бы после присваивания текста ENParam.title блоку он в нем выглядел так:

```
'<div>MAIN</br>TECHNICAL</br>CHARACTERISTICS</div>'
```

однако как этого добиться я не понимаю

Comment: метод [replaceAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) вам в помощь

Comment: Не знаю какая у Вас задача, но на мой взгляд не стоит смешивать данные с их визуальным представлением. Для решения можно использовать CSS стили и что-то в виде шаблонов.

Answer (score 1):

> мне нужно что бы после присваивания текста ENParam.title блоку он в нем выглядел так

Если сделать свойство приватным. Дописать к нему геттер и сеттер. Можно такое осуществить.

https://learn.javascript.ru/property-accessors

```js
const ENParam = {
  _title: null,
  importParamText: 'MAIN CHARACTERISTICS:',
  Capacity: 'Capacity (t/h)',
  Accuracy: 'Accuracy, (%)',
  Voltage: 'Voltage / Frequency, (V/Hz)',
  Power: 'Power, (KW)',
  Weight: 'Weight, (KG)'
}
Object.defineProperty(ENParam, 'title', {
  get() {return this._title},
  set(value) {
    this._title = '<div>' + value.split(' ').join('<br />') + '</div>'
  }
})
ENParam.title = 'MAIN TECHNICAL CHARACTERISTICS'
console.log(ENParam)
```

Comment: а зачем городить весь этот огород? достаточно `ENParam.title.split(' ').join('<br>')`

Comment: @humster_spb, если достаточно - так и сделай. Проблем не вижу...

Comment: @humster_spb,  во. так покатит. спасибо я не допер до банального.

Answer (score -1):

Этого можно добиться разными способами.

Используя регулярные выражения:

```js
console.log('MAIN TECHNICAL CHARACTERISTICS'.replace(/\w+\s/g, m => m.replace(/\s+/g, '') + '<br>'))
```

Или же старые добрые циклы:

```js
let str = 'MAIN TECHNICAL CHARACTERISTICS'
let result = ''

for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  let char = str[i]

  result += char === ' ' ? '<br>' : char
}

console.log(result)
```

А можно и не старые добрые :)

```js
let str = 'MAIN TECHNICAL CHARACTERISTICS'
let result = ''

for (char of str) {
  result += char === ' ' ? '<br>' : char
}

console.log(result)
```

В общем, способов куча, удивлён что вы не нашли не единого способа в итернете.